# GWT Textbox with drop-down arrow

Tags: gwt, layout, widget

I want to have a drop-down arrow in a textbox (actually SuggestBox in my case). GMail does this for advanced search functionality, (opens the advanced search dialog box).

What would be the proper GWT layout to have this arrow show up in the right-hand-side of the TextBox and be clickable?

Looking at GMail, I find a really odd image for the drop-down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

You need to work on the css:

```
public class GMailDropDown implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get().add(new DropDown());
    }

    class DropDown extends Composite 
    implements ClickHandler
    {

        private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        private PushButton button;


        public DropDown() {

              Image img = new Image("https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/zippy/arrow_down.png");

              button = new PushButton(img);

              button.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingLeft(5,  Unit.PX);
              button.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingRight(5,  Unit.PX);
              button.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingTop(3,  Unit.PX);
              button.getElement().getStyle().setPaddingBottom(7,  Unit.PX);

              button.addClickHandler(this);
              button.removeStyleName("gwt-PushButton");

              textBox.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(0, Unit.PX);


              HorizontalPanel panel = new HorizontalPanel();
              panel.add(textBox);
              panel.add(button);

              panel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderWidth(1, Unit.PX);
              panel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderColor("black");
              panel.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.SOLID);

              // All composites must call initWidget() in their constructors.
              initWidget(panel);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

also check this

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomWidgets

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle

Comment: looks very useful, ill give it a try